# Spark scala group by one column breaking another column into list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There's a table storing the time that users listened to music which looks like the follow:

```
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  user | music | listen_time         |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   m   | 2019-07-01 16:00:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   n   | 2019-07-01 16:05:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   x   | 2019-07-01 16:10:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   y   | 2019-07-01 17:10:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   z   | 2019-07-02 18:10:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   A   |   m   | 2019-07-02 18:15:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   B   |   t   | 2019-07-02 18:15:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|   B   |   s   | 2019-07-02 18:20:00 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

The calculation result should be the list of music every user has listened with interval less than 30min, which should looks like (music_list should be ArrayType column):

```
+-------+------------+
|  user | music_list |
+-------+------------+
|   A   |   m, n, x  |
+-------+------------+
|   A   |      y     |
+-------+------------+
|   A   |    z, m    |
+-------+------------+
|   B   |    t, s    |
+-------+------------+
```

How could I possibly implement it in scala spark dataframe?

Comment: What is your dataframe schema?

Comment: @JackieLam what would happened if if a used listened to music at `4:00`, `4:05`, `4:30`, `4:35` ? Should 35 be included in the first group ? In the second one ?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken of course, as the it's only 5 min after the 4:30 one

Comment: Okay, this Can be done with lags and cumulative sums. I will write an answer on monday

Comment: @JackieLam, did that help you? If yes do not hesitate to accept the anwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hint.

```
df.groupBy($"user", window($"listen_time", "30 minutes")).agg(collect_list($"music"))
```

The result is

```
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|user|window                                    |collect_list(music)|
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|A   |[2019-07-01 16:00:00, 2019-07-01 16:30:00]|[m, n, x]          |
|B   |[2019-07-02 18:00:00, 2019-07-02 18:30:00]|[t, s]             |
|A   |[2019-07-02 18:00:00, 2019-07-02 18:30:00]|[z, m]             |
|A   |[2019-07-01 17:00:00, 2019-07-01 17:30:00]|[y]                |
+----+------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

which is similar result but not exactly same. Use `concat_ws` after `collect_list` then you can obtain `m, n, x`.

Comment: this does not work if for instance we have a user A at 17:40. It creates several sessions. But I upvoted the answer thanks for sharing te `window` tick I did not know

Comment: that's true because it does not belong to any 30 minutes interval. The window function split the time into 00~30, 30~00 not 10~40.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
val data = Seq(("A", "m", "2019-07-01 16:00:00"),
("A", "n", "2019-07-01 16:05:00"),
("A", "x", "2019-07-01 16:10:00"),
("A", "y", "2019-07-01 17:10:00"),
("A", "z", "2019-07-02 18:10:00"),
("A", "m", "2019-07-02 18:15:00"),
("B", "t", "2019-07-02 18:15:00"),
("B", "s", "2019-07-02 18:20:00"))

val getinterval = udf((time: Long) => {
(time / 1800) * 1800
})

val df = data.toDF("user", "music", "listen")
.withColumn("unixtime", unix_timestamp(col("listen")))
.withColumn("interval", getinterval(col("unixtime")))


 val res = df.groupBy(col("user"), col("interval"))
.agg(collect_list(col("music")).as("music_list")).drop("interval")
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this kind of exercise, which is a really good exercise to master Spark, is to use lags to create session Ids using cumulative sums.

So the steps are :

- Create a column "newSession" with a literal 1 when this is a new session (If I understood well, more than 30 minuts without lsitening music)
- Create sessions Ids by simply sum the literals 1
- GroupBy Session id newly created and users.

I strongly suggest you to try with the instructions before reading the next part of this answer.

Here is the solution :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Create the data
// Here we use unix time, this is easier to check for the 30 minuts difference.
val df = Seq(("A", "m", "2019-07-01 16:00:00"),
("A", "n", "2019-07-01 16:05:00"),
("A", "x", "2019-07-01 16:10:00"),
("A", "y", "2019-07-01 17:10:00"),
("A", "z", "2019-07-02 18:10:00"),
("A", "m", "2019-07-02 18:15:00"),
("B", "t", "2019-07-02 18:15:00"),
("B", "s", "2019-07-02 18:20:00")).toDF("user", "music", "listen").withColumn("unix", F.unix_timestamp($"listen", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))


// The window on which we will lag over to define a new session
val userSessionWindow = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("unix")

// This will put a one in front of each new session. The condition changes according to how you define a "new session"
val newSession = ('unix > lag('unix, 1).over(userSessionWindow) + 30*60).cast("bigint")

val dfWithNewSession = df.withColumn("newSession", newSession).na.fill(1)
dfWithNewSession.show
/**
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+
|user|music|             listen|      unix|newSession|
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+
|   B|    t|2019-07-02 18:15:00|1562084100|         1|
|   B|    s|2019-07-02 18:20:00|1562084400|         0|
|   A|    m|2019-07-01 16:00:00|1561989600|         1|
|   A|    n|2019-07-01 16:05:00|1561989900|         0|
|   A|    x|2019-07-01 16:10:00|1561990200|         0|
|   A|    y|2019-07-01 17:10:00|1561993800|         1|
|   A|    z|2019-07-02 18:10:00|1562083800|         1|
|   A|    m|2019-07-02 18:15:00|1562084100|         0|
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+
*/

// To define a session id to each user, we just need to do a cumulative sum on users' new Session

val userWindow = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("unix")
val dfWithSessionId = dfWithNewSession.na.fill(1).withColumn("session", sum("newSession").over(userWindow))

dfWithSessionId.show
/**
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+-------+
|user|music|             listen|      unix|newSession|session|
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+-------+
|   B|    t|2019-07-02 18:15:00|1562084100|         1|      1|
|   B|    s|2019-07-02 18:20:00|1562084400|         0|      1|
|   A|    m|2019-07-01 16:00:00|1561989600|         1|      1|
|   A|    n|2019-07-01 16:05:00|1561989900|         0|      1|
|   A|    x|2019-07-01 16:10:00|1561990200|         0|      1|
|   A|    y|2019-07-01 17:10:00|1561993800|         1|      2|
|   A|    z|2019-07-02 18:10:00|1562083800|         1|      3|
|   A|    m|2019-07-02 18:15:00|1562084100|         0|      3|
+----+-----+-------------------+----------+----------+-------+
*/

val dfFinal = dfWithSessionId.groupBy("user", "session").agg(F.collect_list("music").as("music")).select("user", "music").show

dfFinal.show

/**
+----+---------+
|user|    music|
+----+---------+
|   B|   [t, s]|
|   A|[m, n, x]|
|   A|      [y]|
|   A|   [z, m]|
+----+---------+
*/
```